# Profiling synchronization operations in Linux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, profiling, futex

I want to profile synchronization operations, such as locking and unlocking of mutexes, semaphores etc. in Linux.

I know that deep down they are implemented using futexes, so maybe it is enough to profile locking and unlocking of futexes (please correct me if I'm wrong here). So my question is how to profile it, since futex operations normally occur in user space. Is their any tool which allow me to profile this?

I am basically interested in knowing the functions which lock the futexes and the frequency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could be interested by valgrind and it's tool callgrind.

```
valgrind --trace-children=yes --tool=callgrind -v ./program
```

It will generates a detailled callgraph into a file, with among others, the amount of time passed in each function.

Then you can see all of that with kcachegrind, which is a nice UI to visualize the data.

```
kcachegrind
```

It will allow you to see all functions which called pthread_mutex_lock() (or others), and among them, the top ones, by percent of time, ...

The most relevant part of callgrind is that you can easily find bottleneck in single-threaded program, because you just have to look the function which took the most cpu time.

On multithreaded program, a function waiting a long time for something (a mutex) is a normal condition, so it's more difficult.

You can also use the tool Helgrind from valgrind, which help find errors in your usage of mutexes (potential deadlocks or potential data races).

**I guess** that it analyses your calls to synchronization functions, and the data you read/write, to detect potential problem (problem that could occur 1 time over 1000000), by analyzing the [Serializability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serializability) conformance of your synchronization and data access. (I repeat : I guess).

```
valgrind --tool=helgrind --suppressions=$PWD/supp --gen-suppressions=yes --db-attach=yes --track-lockorders=no ./program
```

And the core feature of valgrind: Checking memory leak:

```
valgrind --leak-check=yes -v --db-attach=yes ./program
```

Comment: So once again valgrind comes to our rescue :)!